# How to add zoomhome plugin to leaflet map in ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, ionic4, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to add the [zoomHome](https://github.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome) plugin to my [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com/) in my ionic app.

The map is displaying as expected before adding this code.

I added the below code inside the `<head>` section of `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="assets/external-assets/leaflet.zoomhome.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/external-assets/leaflet.zoomhome.css" />
```

In my assets folder, I created a sub folder called external-assets, & copied the following files from 
https://github.com/torfsen/leaflet.zoomhome/tree/master/dist :

- leaflet.zoomhome.css
- leaflet.zoomhome.min.js

Here, I set the default zoom as false:

```
this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [lat, lng],
      zoomControl: false
    });
```

Then I add the zoomHome control:

```
let zoomHome = L.Control.zoomHome({ position: 'topright' });
zoomHome.addTo(this.map);
```

However, when I run ionic serve, I get this console error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
>   at leaflet.zoomhome.min.js:5

This error is also logged:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Control.zoomHome is not a
>   function TypeError:
>   leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Control.zoomHome is not a
>   function at HomePage.initMap

Can someone please tell me what I’m doing wrong, & how it can be resolved?

Comment: Whereabouts do you load the Leaflet js?

Comment: I don't have a Leaflet js file, I just installed it originally using `npm i leaflet`